# Inputs for flipflops sequential circruits

Tags: flipflop, sequential-logic

Not very sure if these inputs are correct before i draw my truth table.
Too many lines and i am confused.

JA = QB = KA = B
KA = B
DB = D'
TC = 0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Q(t) and Q(t+1) while writing your state equations to avoid confusion.
Also just use QA and QB(and their complements if necessary) instead of using "A" and "B" as outputs.

Hope this helps you:

JA(t) = KA(t) = QB(t)

QA(t+1) = (QA(t)' AND JA(t)) + (QA(t) AND KA(t)')

DB(t) = QB(t)'

QB(t+1) = DB(t)

TC(t) = 0

QC(t+1) = QC(t)